# Accessing map_server using rosjava

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to access the map_server through a client service call to retrieve map information through nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid into my android device using pure implementation Rosjava. However, it seems that there is currently no support for that in Rosjava.

Could anyone help me if you have tried and solved a similar problem?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10871/accessing-map_server-using-rosjava/) by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2011-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know whether it's still the case, but I remember some discussion about not implementing service calls in rosjava.

In any case, you can get the map by subscribing to the [`map`](http://www.ros.org/wiki/map_server#Published_Topics) topic instead of calling a service.

---

Originally posted by [Brian Gerkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/8/brian-gerkey/) with karma: 2916 on 2011-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/854/tuan/) on 2011-08-18**:
Hi, thanks for the reply. I have successfully subscribed to map_server through the latch topic map